# psd to html 1920X1080

Tags: html, css, markup, psd

I have file .psd  with sizes 1920X1080. 
I need to make responsive website that will look good for small and big screens.
I have made from this psd html with pixel perfect technic.
I just don't understand how to make from it design for smaller screens.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CCS3 media queries! Example for Desktop first:

```
// Your code for Desktop devices

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  // Here your code for mobile
}
```

or for Mobile First

```
// Your code for Mobile devices

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  // Here your code for tablet
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  // Here your code for Small Desktop
}
```

Different rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (max-height: 700px) {
      // Code
}
```

or:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-height: 400px) {
      // Code
}
```

These are only some example. You must study media queries.

Comment: what about height? how to adjust height of block for different screens?

Comment: @GeorgeH. height should be dynamic depending on the content